# which rule did we use to simplify this logarithmic equation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$10^\frac{\log{x}}{log{10}}  = x$$

I tried to use all the logarithm rules that i know but i still don't know how to derive this result, any hints please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You start with the rule

$$\frac{\log_a x}{\log_a b} = \log_b x$$

using a = 10, b = 10 to get

$$10^{\log_{10} x} = x$$

And then we use

$$a^{\log_a b} = b$$

Alternatively, you could just recognize that $\log 10$ = 1, because $\log_{x} x = 1$ for all positive x where x does not equal 1. That would simplify the equation to $$10^{\log_{10} x} = x$$ as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can also take the logarithms of both sides. If $$A=10^\frac{\log{x}}{\log{10}}$$ then $$\log(A)=\frac{\log{x}}{\log{10}}\log{10}=\log(x)$$and then $A=x$ by exponentiation of both sides.